# Best way with Egit and Android or AppEngine projects to handle different team member environments

Tags: android, google-app-engine, egit

If each team member on an Eclipse Android or AppEngine project has a different computing environment with, for example, different paths for SDKs, java, etc., what is the best way to set up EGit and a Git repo so that push/pull don't overwrite their particular project properties and/or settings with their particular paths?

My best guess is that these kind of path/directory related project settings that are particular to each computing environment are in files like

```
.classpath  
.project
project.properties
```

and that these should be "assume-unchanged" in Egit.

Are there other files?  Are there better ways to avoid overwriting these kinds of settings/properties with Eclipse or Egit?

Thanks.

Comment: .classpath and .project are Eclipse generated and should not be version-controlled in the very first place.

Comment: why not?  If, for example, I'm the only person working on a project, it would be nice to keep this version controlled also in case I make a change that needs to be undone later, or the like.  In any case, I agree that for team projects these files should not be version controlled, as I've indicated.  But I'm wondering if there are more like them.